# Proxmox VE 6.4 kernel panic during backup to NFS/CIFS

Tags: proxmox, debian-buster, kernel-panic

For a few weeks, we experience systematic kernel crashes during the backup of two distinct Proxmox VE fully-updated 6.4 hosts running on 5.4.114-1-pve Linux kernel. Backups are using the stop mode and a NFS or CIFS mount.

I've taken the two enclosed screenshots of the hosts console after two crashes. They seem to both exhibit the same fib_get_table kernel method. What can I do to further diagnose the problem or avoid the crash ?

[image: kernel panic 1]

[image: kernel panic 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can install and configure `kdump` to gather the kernel core after the crash has occurred, then analyze it  with `crash`. See [this Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/oops-debugging-kernel-panics-0) article for more details.